# Boost::Asio - wake up a thread when there are handlers to run

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

The common way to process Asio handlers is to have a thread (or several threads) either polling `io_service` (i.e. calling `io_service::poll()`) regularly to run the handlers or using `io_service::run()`, which blocks the thread until there's work to do, in which case the thread will run the required handlers and either return or go to sleep again.

However, I want to make a system where a thread is not only responsible for running Asio handlers, but also needs to sync up with another thread using a condition variable. Basically, I want the thread to do all of these:

- Wake up when there are Asio handlers that need to be processed (i.e. if I call `io_service::poll()`, one or more handlers will be processed).
- Wake up when there is non-Asio work to be done, indicated by my condition variable.
- Sleep otherwise.

In other words, I need a way for Asio to signal me that there are handlers ready to execute, without having to busy-wait or continuously poll. Ideally, Asio will somehow signal a thread when work is available, and that thread will in turn wake up my main worker thread, which will process Asio handlers. That worker thread will also be occasionally woken up by yet another thread, and will process other, non-Asio related work.

Is this even feasible, or should I reconsider how I am designing my system?

Comment: I'd reconsider the design. You *could* submit your *other work* to the same queue (io_service) so a single `io_service.run()` handles both, asio and your own tasks.

Comment: @tkausl So my worker thread would be running io_service.run(), and _work_ would be then submitted by both asio, and my other threads, effectively signalling it that there's work to do, right?

Comment: Yes. A `io_service` is *more* than just a queue for asio-tasks. It can handle all kinds of tasks afaik.

Comment: This is an option I haven't considered yet. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction, this is probably the most elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: AFAIK, it already does what you want. For multiple threads running io_service and handlers that access shared resources, then you need to wrap these handlers in a `strand` to enforce that invocation of these handlers is serialized.